# Is there a market amongst programmers for an OID-keyed blob store?

Tags: .net, c++, serialization, storage, blob

A friend has developed a very amazing blob store and I think it needs to be used, but I'm wondering whether people think such a thing has a market, and if programmers ever get to make these kinds of decisions.  It has support for online backups using deltas and is much faster than anything I know of, it's undergone rigorous testing and being used in some very niche applications.  I would think anyone with a binary file format would like to use it as an alternative.  It has a C++ interface and has been adapted to .NET serialisation.

It absolutely blows SQL blob tables out of the water.

Thoughts?

Edit: It is better because:

- It is very fast.
- It is transactional, with a full recovery scan, so far better than flat files.

Answer (score 1):

There's a market, but not a massive one. There is also long-established competition, see [BerkleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) (which was an independently marketted product (company name: SleepyCat), but they were bought by Oracle a while back.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts? You haven't said *how* it is better... (or how it is better to a flat BLOB/database/file solution).

Also, regular .NET (binary) serialization isn't well-suited to long-term storage (in a database), since it is implementation-specific (and tied to the assemblies). For serialization, you might want to look at platform-independent solutions such as Google's protocol buffers (which has implementations for [C++, java](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [C#, and others](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/OtherLanguages)- including [one of my own](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)).

Comment: huh? databases can be used for short term storage.  The .NET wrapper is just an example, we use our own solution for serialisation that caters for schema evolution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the licensing and cost, I'd certainly look at it. I [asked about something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399304/store-huge-stdmap-mostly-on-disk) just a couple weeks ago, and ended up using an SQLite database file for the moment, which I suspect is less than optimal.

(And I run my own software development company, so I *do* make the purchasing decisions. :-) )

Comment: @Head Geek: Jesse and I work together (we run our company too!) - http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/Products/SerialKiller - which we are productizing.  Please excuse the web site as we are still getting marketing material together.  If interested, email us via the address on the Contacts page.